# Python Screen closing when i run test.exe file

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4

Hi all iam new to Python, I have created test.py script then i made exe using "pyinstaller --onefile SNMP_TeamDynamicCheckV1.py " , now i could see "test.exe file in "C:\Python34\Scripts\dist" path. when i run my script my screen getting closed immediately. how keep my screen After Running test.exe file. if provide with solution it would be helpful to me

Comment: Probably it closes because the program ends its execution

Comment: Thanks for reply Shinira , when i run it  in IDLE it's absolutely working fine but only issue with exe file

Comment: Then that's the problem: when you execute the `.exe` it executes in a console window, but you don't make it stay open in any way (with `time.sleep()` for example, like the answer below tells you, or with a `while 1:`), so when the code has been executed, the program ends and the console closes. I'd recommend not to make `.exe` files when working with python. Instead, use the console or the idle, unless you have a reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this happens because the resulting exe is a console application. Default behaviour of these is to close the (new) console window when done.

You can either

- Run it from existing command line window to see the output,
- Modify the program and add keyboard input at the end:
  `input('Press enter to continue')`

Comment: thanks for your reply ,i ran it using command line Please find below out put                                                                                                 C:\Python34\Scripts\dist>python SNMP_TeamDynamicCheckV1.exe
  File "SNMP_TeamDynamicCheckV1.exe", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file SNMP_TeamDynamicCheckV1.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: you need to run `exe` files directly, and cannot open them in python interpreter. `C:\Python34\Scripts\dist\SNMP_TeamDynamicCheckV1.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you like this, but I'll show you an idea.

If you put the code below at the end of your script, the windows will wait for 10 seconds and then close. If you want more or less time, just change the number.

```
import time
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Accepted the answer